# How to create notifications service in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, service

Well, lets say for example, that I want my app to send notifications in certain times (example: 15:00, 17:30)
and the notifications should be sent exactly in the specific time. even if the app is closed (and if the phone was shut down in 15:00, the notification should appear when the phone turned on).

I found that the way to do that, is by background service. but not matter how many times i googled it the service stop working when the app is closed.
Im asking please for code examples of the service, the manifest declaration, in the launch of the service.
pls Kotlin and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of thing you have to use `WorkManager`

1. First you have to add work manager dependency

   ```
   dependencies {
       def version = "2.7.1"

       // Kotlin + coroutines
       implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
   }
   ```
2. Then create a class that extends `Worker`:

   ```
   class NotificationWorker(
         appContext: Context, 
         workerParams: WorkerParameters,
         ): Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
          override fun doWork(): Result {

          // Show notifications ...


          // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
          return Result.success()
         }
    }
   ```
3. Next create work request:

   ```
   val notificationWorkRequest: WorkRequest =
   OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>()
      .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.HOURS) // set your delay
      .build()
   ```
4. Finally, submit your work to the system:

   ```
   WorkManager.getInstance(myContext)
   .enqueue(notificationWorkRequest)
   ```

For more info look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#groovy).

Comment: thanks,for step 3 and 4, where should I put them, and what should I put in the manifest
and for step 3, i want the notifications on certain times on the day ( that changes as they variables)

Comment: You can execute step 3 and 4 in your `activity` or `fragment`. And you don't have to add anything to your manifest. For displaying multiple notifications you can schedule another `worker` after one is completed.

Comment: how do I schedule anouther one? in yor original code its delayed

Comment: In the second step before returning `Result.success()`, you can enqueue another worker.